# strobe media player issue

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, strobe-media-playback

i want to to play media files(video and audio) using strobe media player.
this is the first time i'am using it.
can anybody tell me whats the wrong here:

```
widget('application.extensions.StrobeMediaPlayback.smp.StrobeMediaPlayback',array(
                   //Embed a video  from youtube  with youtube plugin,included by default:  
                     'src'=>$url, 
                      'width'=>'680',
                      'height'=>'400',
                      'allowFullScreen'=>'true'    //default is true                            
));
```

the error is:

```
we are having problems with playback
```

the url: C:\wamp\www\mediastore/files/video/Community1/28237.flv

could you give me some tutorials about strobe media player within yii please ?

network errors:

```
GET http://localhost/mediastore/index.php/files/play/ConfigurationEchoPlugin1.swf 400 (Bad Request) 22:1
GET http://localhost/mediastore/index.php/files/play/ConfigurationEchoPlugin2.swf 400 (Bad Request) 22:1
GET http://localhost/mediastore/index.php/files/play/ConfigurationEchoPlugin1.swf 400 (Bad Request) ConfigurationEchoPlugin1.swf:1
GET http://localhost/mediastore/index.php/files/play/ConfigurationEchoPlugin2.swf 400 (Bad Request) ConfigurationEchoPlugin2.swf:1
```

Comment: thi is the url:

C:\wamp\www\mediastore/files/video/Community1/28237.flv

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the network tab on your browser console? the error is not giving too much information, please provide the link to the extension

Comment: @Asgaroth , i got 4 bad requests

Comment: @Mohammmad Mawed thats cool... do you mind telling us what they say?

Comment: @Asgaroth question edited.